# View.scrollTo(int x, int y) don't work in Android

Tags: android, view, scrollto

I invoke view's scrollTo(int x, int y) when I click the view, but it doesn't move.

code like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

View mView;

int lastScrollX;
int lastScrollY;

Scroller mScroller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mScroller = new Scroller(this);
    mView = findViewById(R.id.test_view);
    mView.setOnClickListener(this);
    lastScrollX = mView.getScrollX();
    lastScrollY = mView.getScrollY();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    lastScrollY += 50;
    lastScrollX += 50;
    mView.scrollTo(lastScrollX, lastScrollY);
    mView.invalidate();
}
```

}

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Try moving the "lastScrollX = mView.getScrollX();
    lastScrollY = mView.getScrollY();" in the onClick function to get the updated scrolls each time.

Comment: Also since your mView is a ScrollView, you should probably change declaration "View mView;" with "ScrollView mView"

Comment: Hi, @Sevle, thanks for you help.

Comment: mView is a ImageView,  and I try moving the "lastScrollX = mView.getScrollX(); lastScrollY = mView.getScrollY();" in the onClick function. 
but it also doesn't move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot scroll an ImageView with the scrollTo function.

ScrollTo() is used to manipulate actual scroll bars that you usually find in a ScrollView or a RecyclerView. When you use ScrollTo the scroll bars are moved with respect to the X,Y that you provide to the function. You do not actually move any views you just move the focus of your screen in a particular place.

You will probably have more luck with something like this:

```
ImageView mView;

float lastScrollX;
float lastScrollY;

...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    lastScrollX = mView.getScrollX();
    lastScrollY = mView.getScrollY();
    lastScrollY += 50.0;
    lastScrollX += 50.0;
    mView.setX(lastScrollX) 
    mView.setY(lastScrollY)
    mView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help

I don't know why scrollTo isn't valid.  Is somethind special in ImageView?

Comment: Added clarification about unsuitability of ScrollTo() function in the post!